# Does the rank nullity theorem work on any field?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Most of linear algebra is done over the fields R and C, but I was wondering if the rank nullity theorem work on any field. If not, then what about algebraically closed fields? Is there some kind of minimal conditions where it holds?

Comment: Works over any field. Read a proof to see that only field axioms are needed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: Most of linear algebra is over an arbitrary field, e.g., vector spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof of the rank-nullity theorem works over any field. Let's see.

Suppose that $K$ is a field, $V,W$ are $K$-vector spaces, and $T:V\to W$ is linear. Fix a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_r$ of $\operatorname{ker} T$. Complete the basis to a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ of $V$. Let $V_0$ be the span of $v_{r+1},\ldots,v_n$. Considered from $V_0$ to $W$, $T$ is injective and its rank is the same. Then
$$
\operatorname{null}T+\operatorname{rank} T=r+(n-r)=n. 
$$